# Network Manager no longer shows wired ethernet (Realtek 8168)

Tags: drivers, network-manager, ethernet, realtek-wireless

Sometime yesterday I lost my wired ethernet network connection. It no longer appears in network manager, nor does it seem to be active in `ifconfig`, though the wireless adapter is.

Possible clues: This seemed to happen shortly after a network-manager (1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2/3) update, but there was also a kernel update (5.4.0-97.110) and system76-driver (20.04.47~1641830102~20.04~12f1c0f~dev, 20.04.48~1643752136~20.04~8120238~dev).

Attempted mitigations: I tried installing the script described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1342203/300877), the r8168-dkms kernel module described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327697/ubuntu-20-04-ethernet-r8168), and doing a full shutdown and restart, to no avail.

Output of possibly relevant commands:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:6d:00.1
       logical name: enp109s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 80:fa:5b:3f:01:33
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:125 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:dc204000-dc204fff memory:dc200000-dc203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:6e:00.0
       logical name: wlp110s0
       version: 78
       serial: 00:28:f8:35:58:4a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.15-76051515-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:dc100000-dc101fff
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: You probably have a cable problem, or whatever hub/switch/router/modem it's plugged into. Also show me `dkms status`.

Comment: Or you need to re-enable it in system settings > network. But in any case you're using Pop!_OS and that's off-topic here.

Comment: OK, I used a different cable and tested it with a nearby Windows system, where it works fine, but does not work when plugged into my laptop.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Describe your network wiring, from the laptop, to the modem. Are you using cat 5e cables? In the Network settings panel, what message is displayed in the Wired Connection box? Is it enabled? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I am using a single cat 5 cable of length roughly 2m from my ethernet port to a Netgear router - the same cable and router that successfully served my Windows box 20 minutes ago. I was able to `ifconfig enp109s0f1 up` and now `lshw` no longer shows it as DISABLED. And there's an encouraging kernel message: `Feb  2 14:03:08 jet-Oryx-Pro kernel: [ 2415.789309] enp109s0f1: 0xffffaa6340071000, 80:fa:5b:3f:01:33, IRQ 125`. Relevant `dkms status` is `r8168, 8.048.00, 5.15.15-76051515-generic, x86_64: installed` which is also encouraging. But pings still give `Network is unreachable`

Comment: cat 5 cables that work on a Windows box really means nothing since we're talking about Linux. Is this a homemade cable? Do you have a cat 5e or cat 6 cable to try? Have you tried another port on the router? Rebooted the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain why this was necessary, but the solution came down to ensuring that the wired interface was "managed". I changed `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` from:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
```

to:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:ethernet
```

And now my wired interface comes up immediately. No new cables, drivers, or scripts were required.