# Wired connection not working on fresh install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have just finished installing a dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. My Ethernet connection works fine on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

The settings menu shows "Wired Connected", without question marks. It seems my configuration is fine but when I disable the WiFi (which works fine) I cannot connect to the internet.

I tried many other suggestions on this site ([Q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342090/wired-connection-stopped-working-after-update-realtek-ethernet-ubuntu-20-04),[Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390757/network-manager-no-longer-shows-wired-ethernet-realtek-8168?newreg=7a2f0e1eaf92453dbd8c1dc95cd003d2),[Q3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267212/ethernet-connection-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04),[Q4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327903/ethernet-connection-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04)), but none worked.

**Additional  Information:**

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
       logical name: wlp45s0
       version: 00
       serial: 34:6f:24:86:55:d1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f irq:190 memory:622c100000-622c1fffff memory:622c200000-622c203fff memory:622c204000-622c204fff

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
       logical name: enp46s0
       version: 15
       serial: 50:eb:f6:30:17:d5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:86204000-86204fff memory:86200000-86203fff
```

`lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet`

```
0000:2e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wwan
```

Comment: Do you get Ip? type ```ip addr list``` Does ```ping 8.8.8.8``` work?

Comment: what is the result if you invoke "ip a " ? This would be interesting! Yes,there are issues with vanilla installations bt they shoud disappear as soon as you create profiles in modem manager GUI.  Other tip: In the CLI do try nmtui-edit and nmtui-connect and nm-connection-editor to see status and options!

Answer (score 0):

There are several reports of issues with driver `r8169` and
adapter *Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]](https://ubuntu.com/certified/component/744)*.

Some solve it with driver `r8168` or [`r8168-dkms`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308793/realtek-r8169-driver-ubuntu-20-04-with-rtl8111-8168-8411-pci-express-gigabit-et#comment2234033_1308793).
You can find `r8168-dkms` [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r8168-dkms).
Please post what you get.

In addition, please post in the OP the output of several commands:

```
$ uname -a
$ lsb_release -a
$ inxi -F
$ systemctl status network-manager.service
$ lspci -vnn | grep -i -A 10 ethernet
```

**Related**

1. [Ubuntu 20.04 Ethernet R8168](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327697/ubuntu-20-04-ethernet-r8168)
2. [Realtek R8169 driver Ubuntu 20.04 (with RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c))](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308793/realtek-r8169-driver-ubuntu-20-04-with-rtl8111-8168-8411-pci-express-gigabit-et)
3. https://askubuntu.com/a/1279662/226614
4. https://www.linux.org/threads/r8168-vs-r8169-tumbleweed.37219/
5. https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/the-age-old-question-r8168-vs-r8169/14247
6. https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:10ec-8168-1028-04b3
7. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1914631
8. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1876593