# Ethernet and wifi not working on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I understand this is a frequent problem and there are many similar questions already, but I cannot find a solution that works for me.

Ubuntu 20.04.4

- Ethernet: Says "wired connected" but I cannot access the internet, not via terminal nor browser.
- Wifi: Says "No wi-fi adapter found"

I have used this pc with ethernet for months with this Ubuntu version, no problems. I have not changed anything since last time I used it two days ago. Router is not the problem, wifi works for my phone.

Many thanks for any help.

ETA: The pc has a wifi adapter, I have used wifi before, but does not seem to recognize it anymore. I have rebooted, deaactivated and reactivated some lan setting in the BIOS, and restarted the network manager, nothing helped.

ETA2: Using RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller from Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. From what I read other people have also had trouble with realtek drivers on Ubuntu.

ETA3: I will try installing r8168-dkms as mentioned here [Wired connection not working on fresh install Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402090/wired-connection-not-working-on-fresh-install-ubuntu-20-04) and hope it solves my problem.